# Creating 4 lists/columns from one list in unix (aix)

Tags: bash, unix, aix

I'm on an AIX system and I've created a list of files from largest to smallest:

```
du -sk /filepath/* | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}'
```

Now, I want to take that list of files and loop them into four lists, i.e:

> ```
> file1
> file2
> file3
> file4
> file5
> file6
> file7
> file8
> ```

etc, to this:

> ```
> file1 file2 file3 file4
> file5 file6 file7 file8
> ```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` is perfect for this:

```
du -sk /filepath/* | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}' | paste - - - -
```

There will be as many columns as the number of `-` arguments.

Comment: Dude! you're a life saver - that's what I needed